# Limit Quantity For the Products With Specific Attribute Magento2

Tags: magento2, php, cart, event-observer, product-attribute

Trying to Limit all the products with having a specific attribute (Yes/No) and others will behave normal.

I have used the event in my module my event.xml

```
 <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_before">
    <observer name="quantitylimiter" instance="Apriljune\Qtylimiter\Observer\CartSaveAfter" />
 </event>
```

My Observer File having the following code:

```
<?php

namespace Apriljune\Qtylimiter\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

class CartSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_productloader;

    protected $_limitConfig = array(
        'Ja' => 3
    );

    public function __construct(
        Session $session,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader
    )
    {
        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        $items = $this->_session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $currentQty = array();



        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($item->getProductId());
            $limitData = $product->getFreeProduct();

            if ( $limitData !=1 ) continue;
            $value = $product->getAttributeText('free_product');

            if (!isset($currentQty[$value])) {
                $currentQty[$value] = 1;
            }
            $currentQty[$value] += $item->getQty();

            $maxQty = 3;
            if ($currentQty[$value] > $maxQty) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException( __( 'Max items allowed for 3 For Sample in Single Order.' ) );
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }
}
```

And module.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Apriljune_Qtylimiter" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

The issue is it is working fine for all the products with with 'free_product' attribute in the cart, but when i add further the normal product without attribute it still not let it add to the cart as it don't have the special attribute.

Comment: Limit for add to cart quantity?

Comment: over add checkout there should be 3 quantity for the products with specific attributes